# how to check if a value is modified from the last time (UPDATE -INSERT) in Cassandra

Tags: transactions, cassandra, timestamp

`if UPDATE USING Timestamp` is the answer, then how does it work?  How can I get the current timestamp value to know if has been modified or not?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [writetime()](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.0/cql/cql_using/use_writetime.html) function to get timestamp of when a cell was written.

```
INSERT INTO excelsior.clicks (userid, url, date, name)
  VALUES (
    cfd66ccc-d857-4e90-b1e5-df98a3d40cd6,
    'http://google.com',
    '2013-10-11', 'Bob'
);

SELECT url, date, name, WRITETIME(name) FROM excelsior.clicks
  WHERE userid = cfd66ccc-d857-4e90-b1e5-df98a3d40cd6;
```

Comment: Hey Chris Thanks for your reply I am using this : String cql1 UPDATE user USING TIMESTAMP 1460707987789 SET  counter = 0 , timestampid = dateof(now()) WHERE id=1   ; doing UPDATE using QueryBuilder.update(cql1) ; I wish to update the value only if the timestamp of the value is the same as it was when I fetched it but doesn't work ! any suggestion